# How can I write an OR condition using node-orm2?

Tags: node.js, orm

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
User.find({'$or': [{user_id: 1}, {user_id: 2}]}, function(err, items){

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes with node-orm2 you can find using 'OR'.

Example :

```
User.find({
        user_id : [ "1", "2" ]
})
```

This will return objects which have used_id = 1 or used_id = 2. It's like a 'IN' condition.